# Authenticating Samba share with AD OU

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, samba, kerberos, share

I'm wanting to link Samba to Active Directory so that I can apply permissions to a share respective to the OU that windows user belongs to.

Im not entirely sure of where to start, I've currently just got a "default" share:

```
[BaccData]
    comment = Bacc Admin Access
    path = /baccdata
    browsable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    read only = no
    create mask = 0755
```

Any starting points would be appreciated, Im shooting in the dark at the moment!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did this for a client project a couple weeks ago. Not my forte, but it turned out to work quite well. CentOS 5.something and SMB with a bunch of storage doing domain authentication for all of the services/users on the Windows servers.

This isn't my favorite way to answer a question, but in this case -- due to how much is covered -- I'm going to offer up a link that was incredibly helpful to me: http://forums.fedoraforum.org/archive/index.php/t-217600.html

To make it "feel" more like Windows shares (specifically around ownership of created folders and such) I added the following lines to my smb.conf:

```
inherit owner = YES
inherit acls = YES
inherit permissions = YES
```